# How navigate back in XML tree to get to an adjacent child element using parent method

Tags: xml, parsing, groovy, xmlslurper

Given the following XML:

```
<list version="1.0">
    <meta>...</meta>
    <resources start="0" count="167">
        <resource classname="Quote">
            <field name="name">USD/KRW</field>
            <field name="price">1024.400024</field>
            <field name="symbol">KRW=X</field>
        </resource>
        ...
     </resources>
</list>
```

In order to find the right `<resource>` and get it's `price` I do the following:

```
def slurper = new XmlSlurper()
def result = slurper.parse(XML_URL)
def node = result.depthFirst().find { it.text() == "KRW=X" }
println node.parent().find { it['@name'] == "price" }.text()
```

However the result is that `parent()` does not implement `find(Closure)` which doesn't quite match with the docs: http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/util/slurpersupport/GPathResult.html

More strange `node.parent().size()` returns 1 when I expect it to return 3 as per the above XML

My questions:

1. Is my code correct and why is not working?
2. Is this the shortest way of achieving the expected result?
3. Why `node.parent().size()` is returning 1 ? The same goes for `node.parent().parent().size()`,  `node.parent().parent().parent().size()` and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
def resource = result.'**'.find { 
    it.field.@name == 'symbol' &&
    it.field.text() == 'KRW=X'
}

println resource?.'**'.find {
    it.@name == 'price'
}?.text()
```

Comment: it says `Cannot invoke method text() on null object`. `resource` is returning `null`

Comment: It totally looks correct. Don't understanding what is wrong with it

Comment: I guess you would need `def resource = result.'**'.find { it.@name == 'symbol' && it.text() == 'KRW=X' }.parent()
`

Answer (score 0):

Something quick and dirty, but this should work:

```
new XmlSlurper().parseText("""
<list version="1.0">
    <meta>...</meta>
    <resources start="0" count="167">
        <resource classname="Quote">
            <field name="name">USD/KRW</field>
            <field name="price">1024.400024</field>
            <field name="symbol">KRW=X</field>
        </resource>

        <resource classname="Quote">
            <field name="name">USD/KRW</field>
            <field name="price">2222</field>
            <field name="symbol">KRW=Y</field>
        </resource>

     </resources>
</list>
""").resources.resource.find{ 
    it.field.find {it.@name == "symbol" && it.text() == "KRW=X"}
}.field.find {it.@name == "price"}.text()
```

Comment: this is basically another equivalent of my own solution. The error is `No such property: field for class: groovy.util.slurpersupport.Node` which surprises me because it should be `slurpersupport.NodeChild`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
def desiredPrice = new XmlSlurper().parse( XML_URL ).'**'.findResult { 
    it.name() == 'field' && it.@name == 'symbol' && it.text() == 'KRW=X' ? 
        it.parent().field.find { it.@name == 'price' }.text() : null
}
```